# How can I Avoid multiple same Events in Forwarded Events in Windows Event Forwarding

Tags: windows-event-log

We use `Windows Event Forwarding` to centralize our Event Logs from around 100 Server.

I get multiple same Events forwarded with same Timestamp. I can't find anything to change that.

It looks like this:

[image]

We use Source initiated forwarding

Comment: Our DomainController are sending these events.

Comment: You're certain those are all identical event records? As in the message text is the same and all have the same event record ID? If that's the case, then check if you have duplicate subscriptions configured. Or perhaps duplicate xpath queries in the applied subscription.

Comment: Yes, those are identical event records. But i have solved the problem. I had duplicate xpath queries applied in my subscription. Thank you for your help.